# C# web service that can have a JS client upload a file to store the file on our IIS Server

Tags: javascript, c#

I have been building a simple c# web service(asmx) for a specific project where the client is a Javascript client.

We now have a requirement that the client can take a photo from their device, such as a tablet that is running the JS web site client side, and that photo needs to be upload to the server via some sort of end point...

All the examples I have been able to find with c# samples is where the client is on a c# web site with a file upload object on it.. but I can't do that as its a JS client.

I assume its possible to have a JS client side app, call and end point in my c# web service and have it upload the file, but I have not been able to figure out how to do this... that is what does the c# end point look like.. We have the JS client side all done just need the web service to deal with the client uploading the image file now..

Thanks

Everything online that I have found is examples of JS to PHP or where the client was on a c# website with a file upload object/control on it..

I have a client side JS web site so struggling to figure out how to do this file upload to our c# web service.

Comment: Since you have JS side of upload done it should be pretty straightforward to come up with server side. Could you please update the question with [mre] of your JS side code that uploads a file and clarify what C# framework/versions you use server side?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.